# How to change subsection heading (e.g. center it)

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, memoir

I'd like to change the styling of `\subsection` in the `memoir` class.

The example is:

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}
\subsection{A subsection - center me!}
\end{document}
```

This is easy enough with sections, eg

```
\setsecnumformat{Section \arabic{section}. \space}
\setsecheadstyle{\bfseries\large\centering}
```

However I wasn't able to find an equivalent for subsections. Is there one, or some alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\large\centering}` seems to do the job:

[image]

The `geometry` package was included only to show the frame of the page for the image capture.

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\subsection{A subsection - center me!}

\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\large\centering}
\subsection{B subsection - center me!}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the centering part see Peters solution

The `\setsecnumformat` is not a good name in this context, because in this case the `sec` part is not changeable (it is a name that has been used in LaTeX). Here is one way to extend it

```
\setsecnumformat{\csname my#1secformat\endcsname}
\newcommand\mysectionsecformat{Section \thesection. \space}
\newcommand\mysubsectionsecformat{Subsection \thesubsection. \space}
\newcommand\mysubsubsectionsecformat{Subsubsection \thesubsubsection. \space}
```