# Left aligned section title

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, amsart

I use a LaTeX template which center aligns all section titles. I want to left align these section titles but I do not know how. I tried

```
\begin{flushleft}
\section{\textbf{Introduction and Background}}
\end{flushleft}
```

but it has no effect on the section title (i.e., it is still centered). I tried

```
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Introduction and Background}
\end{flushleft}
```

and it is left aligned the word "Introduction and Background" but it is no longer a section title and thus the numbering using section number are all messed up.

I am new to LaTeX so please keep it simple.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: Even when trying to keep it simple, knowing which template you use would be *very* helpful. :-)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8546/section-heading-centering-problem) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33903/how-to-change-subsection-heading-e-g-center-it) with centring instead of left align.

Comment: I used the AMS LaTex Article tamplate

Comment: In that case, please accept my answer and (as soon as you have enough reputation) upvote it. ;-)

Comment: Sure will lockstep! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\specialsection{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\centering}}% DELETED
  {\normalfont}}% NEW
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}% DELETED
  {\normalfont\scshape}}% NEW
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction and Background}

\end{document}
```

Note that using formatting macros within section titles as in

```
\section{\textbf{Introduction and Background}}
```

is not the recommended way to make general changes. You should rather use

```
\normalfont\scshape\bfseries
```

in the definition of `\section` (and make sure to use a font that provides bold small capitals).

Also see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)